# Where does AspnetIdentity stores UserTokens?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have ASP.Net MVC5 application. While creating application when you select Individual Authentication visual studio use scaffolding and adds code for Login, Create User, Forgot Password etc. I am using this default implementation of ForgotPassword functionality. This is how the forgot password works.

1>     User click on forgot password link.

2>     User enters his email address.

3>     Application creates new Token and sends email with return URL with Token in the query string.

4>     User clicks on the link in email and gets redirected to ResetPassword page.

5>     User enters new password and hit submit.

6>     Application Validates the user and token and resets the password.

Question.

1>     After receiving email User may not click the link immediately, he may click after sometime or even after few days. In between where does ASP.NET application stores the token? I don’t see it in the database.

2>     Is there any expiration on the token.

3>     On forgot password screen user enters his email and click submit to receive email with token. Let’s say he does this 3 times. So he receives 3 emails with 3 different tokens. Then he clicks on the link from any one email and resets the password.  What happens to unused tokens in other 2 emails, are they still valid? Can user click on link in other email and be able to reset password?

Comment: Can you check my answer ? Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically if you look at the user created by ASP.Net Identity you would see a column `SecurityStamp` which is basically hash and is used in all password related scenarios. In fact it is changed when a user changes his password.

When you click on reset password `SecurityStamp` associated with that user is used to generate the token that is sent in email. See the source code in `GenerateAsync` method here (there are 2 providers)

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider.cs

```
public virtual async Task<string> GenerateAsync(string purpose, UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
    {
        if (manager == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(manager));
        }
        var token = await manager.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(user);
        var modifier = await GetUserModifierAsync(purpose, manager, user);
        return Rfc6238AuthenticationService.GenerateCode(token, modifier).ToString("D6", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

or

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/DataProtectionTokenProvider.cs

```
    public virtual async Task<string> GenerateAsync(string purpose, UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var userId = await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        using (var writer = ms.CreateWriter())
        {
            writer.Write(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
            writer.Write(userId);
            writer.Write(purpose ?? "");
            string stamp = null;
            if (manager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
            {
                stamp = await manager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
            }
            writer.Write(stamp ?? "");
        }
        var protectedBytes = Protector.Protect(ms.ToArray());
        return Convert.ToBase64String(protectedBytes);
    }
```

Once a user clicks on the link and submits new password token sent in email also gets submitted and is validated against the SecurityStamp.

```
    public virtual async Task<bool> ValidateAsync(string purpose, string token, UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
    {
        if (manager == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(manager));
        }
        int code;
        if (!int.TryParse(token, out code))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var securityToken = await manager.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(user);
        var modifier = await GetUserModifierAsync(purpose, manager, user);
        return securityToken != null && Rfc6238AuthenticationService.ValidateCode(securityToken, code, modifier);
}
```

Or

```
    public virtual async Task<bool> ValidateAsync(string purpose, string token, UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
    {
        try
        {
            var unprotectedData = Protector.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(token));
            var ms = new MemoryStream(unprotectedData);
            using (var reader = ms.CreateReader())
            {
                var creationTime = reader.ReadDateTimeOffset();
                var expirationTime = creationTime + Options.TokenLifespan;
                if (expirationTime < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var userId = reader.ReadString();
                var actualUserId = await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                if (userId != actualUserId)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                var purp = reader.ReadString();
                if (!string.Equals(purp, purpose))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                var stamp = reader.ReadString();
                if (reader.PeekChar() != -1)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (manager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
                {
                    return stamp == await manager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
                }
                return stamp == "";
            }
        }
        // ReSharper disable once EmptyGeneralCatchClause
        catch
        {
            // Do not leak exception
        }
        return false;
}
```

Once it successfully validates the token Identity system further updates the user details with new `SecurityStamp`. With all that said answer to your questions

Ans 1 - Token is not stored and link in email is active immediately. I have a fully tested production system and neither me nor users have to wait for the link to be active.

Ans 2- I think the default is 1 day. You can change it by adding below code in `Create` method of `ApplicationUserManager` Class

```
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
 {
  manager.UserTokenProvider =
   new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
      (dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
      {                    
         TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1) //Any custom TimeSpan
      };
 }
```

Ans 3 - Only 1 will work i.e. whichever user clicks first because after that security stamp changes and it will invalidate the token in other 2 emails.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A Thanks you for detailed answer